# Fix clipping on joints

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

My arm rigging looks ok at a more relaxed angle, but when it's bent the forearm and upper arm clip through each other:

[image]

My weight looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I've tried to weight paint back and forth, but it only made the thing worse:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend watching this video or this channel for easy and fast information about rigs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFKORufmsLM Royal Skies on Youtube